# How do I merge Login with Google and Firebase login (storyboard, xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, xcode-storyboard

I have an app with a loginsystem with Firebase. Now it is quite easy to add Login with Google with Firebase. But it isn't easy when I want both, so the user can choose between Login with Google or login with email (Firebase). Can some help me? My current code is the following:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleSignIn

//adding padding to textfields 
extension UITextField {
    func setpadding() {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: self.frame.height))
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
 
//functie aanmaken voor keyboard verdwijnen als je klikt naast het tekst veld
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
 
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
   //
   // adding fields, buttons and labels for the email sign in 
   //

    //Label
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "Log in"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-Bold", size: 30)
        return label
    }()
    
    //Email
    private let emailField: UITextField = {
        let emailField = UITextField()
        emailField.placeholder = "Email Address"
        emailField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        emailField.backgroundColor = .white
        emailField.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        emailField.setpadding()
 
        return emailField
    }()
    
    //Password
    private let passwordField: UITextField = {
        let passwordField = UITextField()
        passwordField.backgroundColor = .white
        passwordField.placeholder = "Password"
        passwordField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        passwordField.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        passwordField.setpadding()
        
        return passwordField
    }()
    
    //Button
    private let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.Blue.darkBlue, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Lets Get Started", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-Bold", size: 20)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        
        return button
    }()
    
    //Button ga verder
    private let GaVerderButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.Blue.darkBlue, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Proceed to app", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-Bold", size: 35)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        
        return button
    }()
    
    
    //!!!!login with google button!!!!!
    @IBOutlet var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
 
    //when view has loaded
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //add fields etc.
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(emailField)
        view.addSubview(passwordField)
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        //functie oproepen voor keyboard verdwijnen als je klikt naast het tekst veld
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

        //!!!!!!!!sign in with google button!!!!!!!!
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        
        //button voor aanmelden met email oproepen door functie uit te voeren als je klikt
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        if FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            label.isHidden = true
            emailField.isHidden = true
            passwordField.isHidden = true
            button.isHidden = true
            
            signInButton.isHidden = true

            //add proceed button when logged in
            view.addSubview(GaVerderButton)
            GaVerderButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 300, width: view.frame.size.width-30, height: 100)
            //call function if button proceed is tapped
            GaVerderButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProceedTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
    
    //make function if button proceed is tapped
    @objc private func ProceedTapped(){
        //Door naar storyboard van de daadwerkelijke app
        print("Proceed clicked")
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToAppIdentifier", sender: self)
    }
    
    //subiews (places etc)
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 80)
        emailField.frame = CGRect(x: 35, y: label.frame.origin.y+label.frame.size.height+20, width: view.frame.size.width-70, height: 50)
        passwordField.frame = CGRect(x: 35, y: emailField.frame.origin.y+emailField.frame.size.height+20, width: view.frame.size.width-70, height: 50)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 35, y: passwordField.frame.origin.y+passwordField.frame.size.height+20, width: view.frame.size.width-70, height: 50)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
 
    @objc private func didTapButton(){
        //test voor onszelf of de button activity is doorgekomen
        print("Continue button tapped")
        
        guard let email = emailField.text, !email.isEmpty,
              let password = passwordField.text, !password.isEmpty
        else{
            print("Email or Password is empty")
            return
        }
        
        //login to account
        FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { [weak self] result, error in
            guard let strongSelf = self else{
                return
            }
            guard error == nil else{
                strongSelf.showCreateAccount(email: email, password: password)
                return
            }
            print("Already signed In")
            strongSelf.label.isHidden = true
            strongSelf.emailField.isHidden = true
            strongSelf.passwordField.isHidden = true
            strongSelf.button.isHidden = true
            
            strongSelf.signInButton.isHidden = true
            
            strongSelf.emailField.resignFirstResponder()
            strongSelf.passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
        })
    }
    
    //pop-up if you dont have an account
    func showCreateAccount(email: String, password: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create account", message: "Would you like to create an account?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: {_ in
            FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { [weak self] result, error in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else{
                        return
                    }
                    guard error == nil else{
                        print("Account creation failed")
                        return
                    }
                    print("Signed In")
                    strongSelf.label.isHidden = true
                    strongSelf.emailField.isHidden = true
                    strongSelf.passwordField.isHidden = true
                    strongSelf.button.isHidden = true
                
                    strongSelf.signInButton.isHidden = true
                
                    strongSelf.emailField.resignFirstResponder()
                    strongSelf.passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
 
            })
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {_ in }))
        
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And I have some other code in the AppDelegate regarding "Login with Google"

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = "........................."
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
 

    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
    
 
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
 
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
 
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            print("Logged in with Google")
            
            ///////dont know what susposed to be here (thats my question)
            /////// because i want login with google aside login with email

        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I would be delightful if someone has an idea!

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is. Authentication for each method is covered in the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start) documentation so when the user clicks or taps Google, use the google auth code. If they tap email, use that code. If you need to link it all together, that is also covered in the docs [Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking). If you're asking something else, can you clarify the question (and shorten the code!)?

Comment: Okay thanks, will do!